# How to convert from DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) format to grayscale

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to open and process a TIF image using python in openCV. I am following this code:

```
Mat img = imread("my.tiff", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

Mat ff_in;
img.convertTo( ff_in, CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0 );  // [0..1] range

Mat ff_out;
dft( ff_in, ff_out );

Mat ff_gray;
ff_out.convertTo( ff_gray, CV_8UC1, 255.0 );
imshow("lalala",ff_gray);
```

I think the code above is in C++ and I'm trying to find the python alternative for it. Here is the link I got it from: [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/9022/how-to-process-tiff-image/)

Currently, I have converted it to python as follow:

```
img = cv2.imread('test2.TIF', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
img1 = np.float32(img)
img2 = cv2.dft(img1);

# What should I use HERE? Convert dft back to gray scale image

cv2.imshow( "Display window", img3);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Any comment or suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The original call to [`convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a3f356665bb0ca452e7d7723ccac9a810) scales by 255.0 (the third parameter) and casts (with saturation) the result to an unsigned 8 bit integer. The first bit is trivial, for saturation use [`np.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) and the last part is `np.uint8`. e.g. `np.uint8(np.clip(img2 * 255, 0, 255))`

Comment: Hi, I added the line `img3 = np.uint8(np.clip(img2 * 255, 0, 255))`, but it did not work. The resulting image looks more like a dft. Do you know whether anything else might be wrong in steps 1 and 2 (convert to float32 and dft)?

Comment: Well, your conversion into `float32` is missing the scaling by `1.0/255.0` (i.e. the second line should be something like `img1 = np.float32(img) / 255.0`). The rest seems to match.

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant: `img1 = np.float32(img / 255.0)` or `img1 = np.float32(img, 1.0 / 255.0)`, but both don't work. Also, np.float32 only accepts one argument.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to convert it using the following code:

```
img = cv2.imread('test.TIF', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED)   # img.dtype = uint16

img1 = np.float32(img / 255.0) # img1.dtype = float32

img2 = np.uint8(np.clip(img1 * 255, 0, 255)) # img2.dtype = uint8

cv2.imshow( "Display window", img2);
cv2.imwrite('test.png', img2)
```